# WooCommerce REST API Products not creating attributes

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I’ve seen a post similar to this one, but I haven’t found the answer yet. Can you please help me?

I’m trying to create a variable product using the woocommerce REST API, but the attributes for the variations don’t seem to be created. These are my steps:

1. Send a post request for the product of the variable type, specifying 2 attributes (color and size). Here seems to be the issue, because the response shows no attributes and if I go to editing the product, the attributes (color and size) don’t seem to be there. I've tried both global and product level attributes.
2. Send a post request creating a product variant, using a variation combination from step 1. I get no errors, but the product doesn’t seem to be created, nor the variant appears on my store site or when I edit the product on the website admin.

I’ll post my calls and the responses here, I really hope you can help me. I've tried using the V2 and V3 API, but no difference.

Thanks a lot!!!!

1A: My POST of the variable product:

```
    "name": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "slug": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "type": "variable",
    "description": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "short_description": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "KVTA"
        }
    ],
    "sku": "KVTA",
    "manage_stock": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 46
        },
        {
            "id": 47
        },
        {
            "id": 48
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "position": 0,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "Options": [
                "G",
                "M"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "position": 0,
            "visible": true,
            "variation": true,
            "Options": [
                "BEGE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1B: The response I get. Mind that the response doesn’t give me any erros, but it doesn’t return the attributes either.

```
    "id": 1500,
    "name": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "slug": "chapeu-hering-fem",
    "permalink": "https://woocriar.com/product/chapeu-hering-fem/",
    "date_created": "2021-03-22T12:32:46",
    "date_created_gmt": "2021-03-22T12:32:46",
    "date_modified": "2021-03-22T12:32:46",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2021-03-22T12:32:46",
    "type": "variable",
    "status": "publish",
    "featured": false,
    "catalog_visibility": "visible",
    "description": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "short_description": "CHAPEU HERING FEM",
    "sku": "KVTA",
    "price": "",
    "regular_price": "",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "on_sale": false,
    "purchasable": false,
    "total_sales": 0,
    "virtual": false,
    "downloadable": false,
    "downloads": [],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "external_url": "",
    "button_text": "",
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "manage_stock": true,
    "stock_quantity": null,
    "backorders": "no",
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "sold_individually": false,
    "weight": "",
    "dimensions": {
        "length": "",
        "width": "",
        "height": ""
    },
    "shipping_required": true,
    "shipping_taxable": true,
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": 0,
    "reviews_allowed": true,
    "average_rating": "0",
    "rating_count": 0,
    "upsell_ids": [],
    "cross_sell_ids": [],
    "parent_id": 0,
    "purchase_note": "",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 46,
            "name": "ACESSÓRIO",
            "slug": "acessorio"
        },
        {
            "id": 47,
            "name": "CHAPÉU",
            "slug": "chapeu"
        },
        {
            "id": 48,
            "name": "Feminino",
            "slug": "feminino"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "images": [],
    "attributes": [],
    "default_attributes": [],
    "variations": [],
    "grouped_products": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "price_html": "",
    "related_ids": [],
    "meta_data": [],
    "stock_status": "outofstock",
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://woocriar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1500"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://woocriar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

2A: My post of a product variant

```
    "sku": "0001047123",
    "regular_price": "65.90",
    "manage_stock": true,
    "status": "publish",
    "stock_quantity": 1,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "option": "G"
        },
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "option": "BEGE"
        }
    ]
}
```

2B. The response I get. It seems ok, but it doesn’t show on my store nor when I try to edit the product.

```
    "id": 1501,
    "date_created": "2021-03-22T12:34:37",
    "date_created_gmt": "2021-03-22T12:34:37",
    "date_modified": "2021-03-22T12:34:37",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2021-03-22T12:34:37",
    "description": "",
    "permalink": "https://woocriar.com/product/chapeu-hering-fem/",
    "sku": "0001047123",
    "price": "65.90",
    "regular_price": "65.90",
    "sale_price": "",
    "date_on_sale_from": null,
    "date_on_sale_from_gmt": null,
    "date_on_sale_to": null,
    "date_on_sale_to_gmt": null,
    "on_sale": false,
    "status": "publish",
    "purchasable": true,
    "virtual": false,
    "downloadable": false,
    "downloads": [],
    "download_limit": -1,
    "download_expiry": -1,
    "tax_status": "taxable",
    "tax_class": "",
    "manage_stock": true,
    "stock_quantity": 1,
    "stock_status": "instock",
    "backorders": "no",
    "backorders_allowed": false,
    "backordered": false,
    "weight": "",
    "dimensions": {
        "length": "",
        "width": "",
        "height": ""
    },
    "shipping_class": "",
    "shipping_class_id": 0,
    "image": null,
    "attributes": [],
    "menu_order": 0,
    "meta_data": [],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://woocriar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1500/variations/1501"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://woocriar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1500/variations"
            }
        ],
        "up": [
            {
                "href": "https://woocriar.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/1500"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify that I got a solution. My POST had "Options" instead of "options" (capital "O"), this was all. It didn't return any errors, just didn't do anything.
After using lowercase "o" on the options to the attributes, it worked.

Thank you all.